# Get DataTable from aspx using VB 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a VB 2010 desktop application. I use the lines below to get a string response from an aspx page that I use to collect online data for the application.

```
Dim response As Byte() = myWebClient.UploadValues(myWeb & "/Default.aspx", "POST", nmv)
dim str as string = Replace(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response), "<(.|\n)*?>", "")
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response)
```

'nmv' is a defined NameValueCollection variable

Now I need to get this data back from the aspx page as either as nmv or a datatable. Is that possible? How could I go about doing it? I am thinking the key is in the System.'Array'... or something but I can't figure it out and I don't get any search results on the web.

Getting the data back as a *string array* is good for me, getting it **nmv** is even better; but getting it back as a ***DataTable*** would be perfect! I am able to deal with the aspx page giving back the data in any format, I just need the vb app to know how to collect it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe easiest way would be to use *.ashx Http Handler (generic handler) and save DataTable to XML, something like this :

Server:

```
  public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
  {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      /// if needed request data is in context.Request
      DataTable tbl = GetDataTable();
      /// table must have name, if not WriteXml will fail
      tbl.TableName = "TableName";
      tbl.WriteXml(context.Response.OutputStream);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
      get
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Then on client you should use ReadXml DataTable method to populate DataTable on client.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the content type of the aspx from text to image or pdf etc. but not a complex datatype.

I would use a web service or wcf service instead. You can just declare a method of DataTable type and you're done.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Ted. I was beginning to think I was trying the impossible :)! Not a new question... but I guess that means I also can't read the values of, say web session, from my vb app?

Comment: That is quite far fetched I'm afraid! Session variables are only available on the server-side and for the specific session only!

Comment: Great to know early... web, here I come :)